# Android Google places API GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions() sorted by distance from actual location

Tags: android, google-places-api

Before that, I've used some REST Google places API for my autocomplete text view. And I remember that the results were somehow relevant to my actual location.

Now, they added [new simplier api](https://developers.google.com/places/android/autocomplete) with `GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions()` method to get the first predictions. But I can't find any way to add some sorting parameters to query. Moreover, I must add the bounds explicitly.

So, my question is: is there any way to get predictions based somehow on my current location, but for all places in the world? Or should I use another/older api for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no way to provide your own sorting parameters. The results are sorted by relevance, which includes but is not limited to distance. According to the [GeoDataApi documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/GeoDataApi), the bounds you provide are used...

> for geographically biasing the autocomplete predictions.

This means that when it is relevant, you will still get results outside of the bounds. So to answer your question; you can get results from all over the world, but it will *prefer* results that are within the bounds you specify. There is no way to force it to order strictly by distance, but in most cases this is a good thing. When someone types "New York" they are usually referring to the city or state, even if they are thousands miles away, rather than the New York Life office building that is probably closer.

Comment: thanks, I was guessing something like that, but now you made it clear

Comment: You can sort them yourself using `distanceBetween` or `distanceTo` methods of `Location`.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, you cannot get a Location object from the Places API. Only an AutocompletePrediction object https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/AutocompletePrediction

Comment: probably will need to reverse geocode this before it can be located with lat lon.